# When will device report status to cloud/pubsub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, mdm, android-management-api

I already set up Pub/Sub notifications and I want to know when the device will notify status reports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status report should happen a few times per day, when the device checks in with the server. When the status report happen a Pub/Sub notification is sent.